Add custom flow trigger in Shopware 6.6
I have a question: i created a custom flow trigger using this documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-trigger.html . It works correctly below Shopware 6.6.
In Shopware 6.6.3.1, the events.json file throws in the backend in the list view of the flows a 500 error message with the following error:
Event <Vendor>\\<Extension>\\Events\\<MyEvent> is not a business event

The error comes from the file BusinessEventCollectorSubscriber.php from the line:
$definition = $this->businessEventCollector->define(MyEvent::class);

But I implemented it as described in the documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/flow/add-flow-builder-trigger.html#add-your-new-event-to-the-flow-trigger-list
How can the problem be solved under Shopware 6.6?

The solution for this below Shopware 6.6 is: class MyEvent extends Event implements ..., FlowEventAware
